# Taxomony menu - show all, vocabulary link are disabled

Tags: navigation, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom vocabulary which looks something like this:

Shops (vocabulary name)

- Sporting Goods
- Auto Parts
- Computers
- Etc. (15 items in total, 1 level)

My goal is to create a menu link to Shops and a drop-down sub menu that lists different types of shops (example - Auto Parts). Shops link must be in the main menu.

I have PathAuto installed and all term have their aliases. My problem is that the exact two options from Taxonomy Menu module while editing my vocabulary are disabled:

Add item for vocabulary **(disabled)**

*Shows the vocabulary name as the top level menu item of the taxonomy menu.*

Use 'all' at the end of URL **(disabled)**

*This changes tid+tid+tid to "All" in term when Display descendants has been selected.
Only used if Menu path type is "Default path".
Works with default taxonomy page.*

Menu path type is set to Default.

Why are they disabled ? Is this the appropriate module for this kind of menu ? Should this be constructed with Views module (haven't got round to it)

Since I am just beginning to learn drupal, I'd like to use as few modules as necessary, since there is probably a module for everything, but they would only probably bloat the site and I wouldn't learn anything.

Bonus question: are there any simple, widely used D7 themes with built in drop-down menus (currently using Bartik)?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on an ecomerce project and faced same issue. This helped https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBdVW7fC2Tg me so I recommend watching it, For the listing I have used drupal nice menus module. You can use it from https://drupal.org/project/nice_menus. In my project, listing is now working fine and I have 4 different menu items with their respective sub-categories.
[image: any]

If you still face any issues I will be available to help!